# Show last, last two or last three nodes depending on role

Tags: views

I'm working on a site where members can have three different roles.
Gold, Silver and Bronze.

Now I'm trying to set up a view that will display the:
last three nodes of all Gold members and
last two nodes of all Silver members and
the last node of all Bronze members,

I want all these nodes displayed together on the homepage, randomly ordered. And I just can't figure out how to do this.

I can make a view that shows all last nodes of all users. And I tried working this out with "views field view" making different views showing nodes per user and combining these views in one view but then I am not able to randomly order them.

Well I hope someone can help me out here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally solved it. What I basically wanted but wasn't able to find the right words for is to merge content of two views. Basically it's not necessary to have two views. It's possible to use one filter with AND/OR logic use of the filter option. All is explained in this wonderfull post:

http://www.webomelette.com/drupal-views-filters-and-or-logic

Thanks for thinking with me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a fresh (block) view that displays all nodes.  Then you can add a relationship to `Content: Author`.

After adding the relationship, you will be able to add a new filter for `User: Roles` that uses the Author relationship.  Set this filter to your Gold member role.  Set the view to display 3 items.

Add a new Attachment display:
[image]

Under attachment settings, attach it to your first views display (the gold member display).  Attachment position should be "After".  Set the User: Roles filter to show Silver members and set the "Items to display" to 2 items.

Add another Attachment view and repeat the last steps, setting the User: Role to Bronze and changing the Items to display to 1.

Now when you view the block, it will show 3 gold, 2 silver and 1 bronze node.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your post and reminding me of the Attachment function of views. But this won't work like I want. Because this only works when I have one member of each role.
When I for instance have two gold members, I want the last three nodes of each gold member is shown.

Comment: This does not limit anything to a specific user, it will show 3 gold, 2 silver, 1 bronze pulled from all users.  The only way it would be limited to a specific user is if you add a filter for a specific user.

Comment: Was your intention to show more than the 3,2,1?  For example if you have 10 gold members, do you want to show 30 gold member's posts?

Comment: Yes! That's what I want.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I got this thing figured out (almost) using the Attachment was the key I think, I can output what I want, but now I have a ordering issue. Using the attachment I can choose to place it before or after the content. This way it's not possible to scramble all nodes.

What I want is that the output of the page and both attachments are combined and can be scrambled and ordered randomly. Is this possible?